# In Prestashop After Shifing Server-In Admin-Product etc. Pages showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: server, prestashop, database-schema, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am using PrestaShop 1.7.5.2 and recently changed my server & now the problem is that in my admin few pages are not working like "Products, Invoices, Stocks, Module Manager, Module Catalogue, Theme Catalogue etc.

My front end is working fine.

I have read almost all the content available but was not able to find exact solution to it.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks,

GC
Edited just now by gauravchawla18 (see edit history)

Comment: Turn on DEBUG mode.

Comment: Hi,After turning Debug bug mode on I am getting so may errors, homepage and admin panel both have stopped working. Please send you personal mail adress will send you the screen shorts there

Comment: Please upload here :)

Comment: Hi Please check both links http://www.gohotsports.com/content/10-home-page-error?adtoken=9995fad5827603be0bbf7e1728736e94&ad=xf6skuukse5jwwty&id_employee=1                                                                                                                            http://www.gohotsports.com/content/11-backend-admin-page?adtoken=9995fad5827603be0bbf7e1728736e94&ad=xf6skuukse5jwwty&id_employee=1

Comment: Your database is incomplete. At least `ps_translation` table is missing. Please check if your did the export or the import wrong.

Comment: Great..... You gave the right solution as few of tables were missing. All is opening now and thanks for your wonderful help

Answer (score 0):

Your database is incomplete. At least `ps_translation` table is missing.

Please check your database import.